# False positive rate of Bloom Filter

Tags: machine-learning

A  [Bloom Filter](http://blog.smola.org/post/4206530042/bloom-filters) is used to identify if an element $x$ in a data stream is a member of some set $S$. What's the false positive rate of a Bloom filter with a single hash function $h(.)$?

Answer (score 1):

Assume that the bloom filter (BF) uses an underlying bit array $(A)$ of size $n$ bits. It works this way:

### Populating BF

- Hash each element $x$ of set $S$ using $h(X)$ to a slot in A and set the bit of that slot to 1
- fraction of slots with bits on  (say $P$)= $1-(1-1/n)^{|S|}$ where $1/n$ is the probability of a given slot being hit by a given element $x_{1}$ and $(1-1/n)^{|S|}$ is the probability of a given slot not being hit by any $x \in S$.  $$P=1-(1-1/n)^{n(|S|/n)}$$ By $$\lim _{\epsilon \to 0}(1-\epsilon)^{1/\epsilon}=1/e$$  where $1/n \approx e$ we finally get $$P=1-e^{-|S|/n}$$

  ### Using BF

  - Now assuming that a $y \not\in S$ arrives the probability of a false positive is exactly the probability that it'll hash to an *on* bit = # fraction on bits in $A$ since $h(.)$ is a uniform random hash $= 1-e^{-|S|/n}$